# Why this PowerShell replacement command encounters error?

Tags: command-line, powershell

I have a script that replaces the content of a given file:

```
set IsSecure=false
if "%Protocol%" == "https" (
    set IsSecure=true
)

powershell -Command "(gc %PublishRoot%\Settings.json) -replace '\"IsDeveloping\"\: \"true\"', '\"IsDeveloping\": \"false\"' | Out-File %PublishRoot%\Settings.json" -encoding utf8
powershell -Command "(gc %PublishRoot%\Settings.json) -replace '\"IsSecure\"\: \"(true|false)\"', '\"IsSecure\": \"%IsSecure%\"' | Out-File %PublishRoot%\Settings.json" -encoding utf8
```

The first line works and `"IsDeveloping": "true"` becomes false.

But the second line that uses a variable, gives me this error:

> "', '"IsSecure": "true"' | Out-File C:\path-to-publish\Settings.json" was unexpected at this time.

Comment: You have not provided us enough of your script to reproduce your issue.  Can you provide a minimal example to reproduce the issue that can be ran and debugged?

Comment: @AilEXE based on the code you provided, I copied that into PowerShell ISE and see the `(true|false)` on that line is not a string so I suspect that's what is causing your issue https://i.imgur.com/ykHo7U9.png. While you did not provide a JSON example file for anyone to test with the content you are having issues, based on what you provided, I was able to debug at that level per a syntax issue. You will need to escape the pipe and parenthesis with the backtick or enclose the parenthesis is double quotes like this: https://i.imgur.com/ogek8Vk.png. For 100% accuracy, JSON content example needed.